# Excel 2010 removes data from clipboard, how can I stop it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, clipboard

- The order of my actions is:

  1. Copy data from pivot table from second sheet.
  2. Paste data as value into first sheet.
  3. Notice that something is wrong in the data.
  4. Go back to the second sheet and change data.
  5. Copy data from changed data.
  6. Return to first sheet.
  7. Select and delete wrong data.
  8. Try to paste new copied data from second sheet but clipboard is empty.

Why does Excel remove data from the clipboard when I select and delete data from a sheet? How can I change this strange behavior?

Comment: That is normal behavior in Excel. Delete the wrong data first then copy and paste. Or just paste over the wrong data.

Comment: @CharlieRB: IMNSHO, that’s an answer.  Why don’t you post it as such?

Comment: Typing into a cell after copying, applying formatting to a cell and sometimes opening a new workbook empty the clipboard as well.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is normal behavior in Excel.

Simply rearrange the order of how you are doing things should help. For instance, delete the wrong data first then copy and paste. Or just paste over the wrong data.

You can also use the Office Clipboard to save up to 24 items to reuse - [Copy and paste multiple items by using the Office Clipboard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-and-paste-multiple-items-by-using-the-office-clipboard-HA010163602.aspx)

[image]

Comment: I think is not normal behavior, I make some tests. On the image http://i.imgur.com/HtdGjFb.png 1- new sheet 2- input some text 3- copy text to clipboard 4 - delete text from sheet but clipboard is not empty. Try to paste (Ctrl+V) text from clipboard, but nothing happens. If click button <Paste All> from Clipboard panel, magically (Ctrl+V) starts to work. Can you test this actions on your computer?

Comment: Yes, that is normal behavior. Using keyboard shortcuts marks the selection, then copies the selection as soon as you tell it where you want to paste it. If you do anything else, it cancels the operation. I don't think it actually puts it on the clipboard unless you have the clipboard window open.